# Formal proof of a simple fact, namely that $S$ has even cardinality if certain pairs could idenitifed

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $S$ be a finite set such that to each $s \in S$ there corresponds exactly one $t \ne s$ such that $t$ uniquely corresponds to $s$. Then $S$ has even order.

This is quite obvious, an argument would be to group the elements of $S$ in pairs and then $|S| = 2\cdot \mbox{''number of different''}$ pairs. But how would you proof this in a more formal way, i.e. we must proof that $S = A \cup B$ disjoint with $|A| = |B|$. How to choose the sets $A$ and $B$?

One first step might be to formulate it in more mathematical terms, maybe $S$ is finite and there exists some involution $f$ on $S$ with no fixed points, then $S$ has even cardinality.

Then there comes a heuristic/algorithmic argument to my mind, by erasing pairs in sets $\{ s, f(s)\}$ we always erase two, and no such element left in $S$ could be mapped to an element already erased. As $S$ is finite this must terminate, either with $S$ containing just one element, or no element. The first case is not poosible, as $S = \{s\}$ would imply $f(s) = s$ which is excluded, hence at termination $S$ must be empty, so we set as $A$ the $s$ elements removed, and $B$ are their images.

I do not think this is satisfactory, I tried to turn it into an inductive argument, but then over what should the induction go without already assuming that $|S|$ is even (number of pairs, order...)

My second try goes by an equivalence relation $s \sim t$ if $t = f(s)$ or $s = t$. Then the equivalence classes have the form $\{s, f(s)\}$ and $S = \bigcup_s \{s, f(s) \}$. In this union two sets are either disjoint or equal, which shows that $S = A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_k$ for disjoint sets of order two. Now it is again quite obvious that $S$ is even, as $A$ choose from each $A_i$ one element, $B$ is the set of elements not choosen. But still this argument seems so complicated, so there might be a simpler, yet formal argument of this fact?

I know this is a very basic question and I see that this fact is true and obvious. But what I am asking here is a formal proof of this fact, which I suppose by the simplicity of the fact must be simple to (or is this not always the case, maybe also simple facts might have quite technical proofs if written out)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, as you suggest, that $S$ is finite and $f$ is an involution on $S$ with no fixed points. Let $A$ be a subset of $S$ *maximal* subject to $$A\cap f(A)=\emptyset.$$ Let $B=f(A)$.

Then $A\cap B=\emptyset$. And $A\cup B=S$: If $x\notin A\cup B$ then also $f(x)\notin A\cup B$, hence $A'=A\cup\{x\}$ contradicts the maximallty of $A$.

And $|A|=|B|$ since $f$ is a bijection between the two sets. So $|S|=|A|+|B|=2|A|$.

Comment: You all gave great answers, and I really like all of them! But as I need to select one, I choose this for its conciseness and somewhat unusual construction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be a finite set, we may assume wlog. that it is linearly ordered. Given a map $f\colon S\to S$, we can define
$$A:=\{\,s\in S\mid f(s)<s\,\} $$
$$B:=\{\,s\in S\mid f(s)>s\,\} $$
$$C:=\{\,s\in S\mid f(s)=s\,\} $$
Clearly $S$ is the disjoint union of $A,B,C$.
If additionally $f$ is an involution, then $f$ maps $A\to B$ and $B\to A$. As the composition of these maps is the identity (both ways), theses maps are in fact bijections, so that $|S|=|A|+|B|+|C|=2|A|+|C|$. Finally, if $f$ has no fixed points then $|C|=0$ and $|S|=2|A|$.

---

Your second argument is also fine as from the disjoint union of two-sets we have
$$|S|=\left|\bigcup_i A_i\right|\stackrel{\text{(disjoint!)}}=\sum_i|A_i|=\sum_i2=2\sum_i1$$

Answer (score 1):

Because $S$ is a finite set, you can prove this by induction on the cardinality of $S$ i.e. $|S|$, which we abbreviate to $n$. We want to show that odd $n$ implies a contradiction. For $n = 1$ this is clearly true. Now, for $n = 2k + 1$, we choose any element $s$ from the set. Our condition allows us to choose the associated $t$ and form the set $\{s, t\} \cup (S - \{s, t\}) $ whose cardinality is $2$ plus the cardinality of $(S - \{s, t\})$. Now, the cardinality of the remaining set, call it $S' = (S - \{s, t\})$ is $2k - 1$, which is odd. And we know that the uniqueness pairing condition must hold for $S'$. This is because any element $s'$ of $S'$ has to have some unique $t'$ in $S$, but by uniqueness $t'$ cannot be $t$ or $s$ and so must be in $S'$. But then we get that the condition holds for an odd set $S'$ with cardinality less than this one. Which is a contradiction by induction. So we have that $n$ must be even.

Comment: With this idea you can prove the theorem directly. You don't need the extra baggage of a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @EthanBolker, yes you can use induction to prove the theorem directly, but I see no harm in using contradiction. Note that this is a *constructive* form of contradiction, so it's not really much "extra baggage" . I.e. it would pass in a theorem prover such as Coq.

Comment: I agree that formally it's equivalent. In that sense there's no harm in it. But to my taste the direct proof is cleaner. Since not all proofs by contradiction are constructive and students can't appreciate the distinction I want them to look for direct proofs when possible.

Comment: In general I agree, but in this case the proof by contradiction came cleaner to me. Can you sketch out the direct proof, maybe I have something different in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be your involution, and $n$ the number of elements of $S$.

Let $S_0 = \emptyset$, $A_0 = B_0 = \emptyset$, and $R_0 = S - S_0$. The set $R$ denotes the "remaining elements", intuitively.

For $k > 0$:

(1) If $R_{k-1}$ is empty, define $S_k = S_{k-1}$, $A_k = A_{k-1}$, $B_k = B_{k-1}$; and $R_k = \emptyset$.

(2) Otherwise, let
$x \in R_{k-1}$, and define 
$$
S_k = S_{k-1} \cup \{ x, f(x) \}\\
R_k = S - S_{k}\\
A_k = A_{k-1} \cup \{ x\} \\ 
B_k = B_{k-1} \cup \{ f(x)\}.
$$

Then let $A = A_n$, $B = B_n$. (Actually, $n/2$ would suffice, but $n$ is easier to write in a subscript!)

It's easy to prove that $A_k$ and $b_k$ are disjoint, and that their union is $S_k$; it's easy to see that $S_n = S$ (indeed, $S_{n/2} = S$, but the former is simpler).

This *is* surprisingly messy, but when you need to invoke finite-ness, something like induction is going to be essential.

An alternative: to say $S$ is finite is to say that there's a bijection $b$ between $S$ and some initial segment, $1, 2, \ldots, n$ of the integers.

Then let

$$
A = \{ x \in S | b(x) < b(f(x)) \},\\
B = \{ x \in S | b(x) > b(f(x)) \}.
$$
These are clearly disjoint, in 1-1 correspondence, and their union is $S$.

Comment: For case (2). Do you forgot to define $R_k$? Guess it must be $R_k := R_{k-1} \setminus\{x, f(x)\}$.

Comment: Fixed. Your guess was correct, but I used a slightly different form to make it clear that at each stage, $S_k \cup R_k = S$. :)

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ has no a priori structure (like an order) you need some sort of "finite choice axiom" to exhibit a partition of $S$ into two sets $A$ and $B$ with $|A|=|B|$. But in order to prove that $|S|$ is even it is enough to show that $|S|=2\cdot n$ for some $n\geq1$. Your equivalence class argument perfectly does the job: Every equivalence class has $2$ elements, and the union of these classes is $S$.